# How to correctly initialize member variable of template type?

Tags: c++, templates

suggest i have a template function like following:

```
template<class T>
void doSomething()
{
    T a; // a is correctly initialized if T is a class with a default constructor
    ...
};
```

But variable a leaves uninitialized, if T is a primitive type. I can write T a(0), but this doesn't work if T is a class. Is there a way to initialize the variable in both cases (T == class, T == int, char, bool, ...)?

Comment: edited question tittle to avoid  ambiguousness if  a template variable or member of template is meant. There is some template magic related to former.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Like so:

```
T a{};
```

---

Pre-C++11, this was the simplest approximation:

```
T a = T();
```

But it requires `T` be copyable (though the copy is certainly going to be elided).

Comment: just noticed, that something like `int i = bool()` does work aswell... why is this legal ?!... is `bool()` some kind of function in this case ?

Comment: btw, `unsigned int i = unsigned int();` doesnt compile with GCC, but is it legal ?

Comment: @smerlin:  I've answered your first question, and formally asked your second question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144012/explicit-type-conversion-and-multiple-simple-type-specifiers; I believe the answer is that this is not valid for types specified by a combination of simple type specifiers, e.g. `unsigned int`.

Comment: `identity<unsigned int>::type()`. Meta-parenthesizer xD

Comment: @Johannes Schaub  why not `unsigned  i = unsigned();` ? `int` is implied in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Class template field in C++11 has the same syntax:

```
template <class T>
class A {
  public:
    A() {}
    A(T v) : val(v) {}
  private:
    T val{};
};
```