# Variable initialization in C++

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

My understanding is that an `int` variable will be initialized to `0` automatically; however, it is not. The code below prints a random value.

```
int main () 
{   
    int a[10];
    int i;
    cout << i << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

- What rules, if any, apply to initialization?
- Specifically, under what conditions are variables initialized automatically?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It will be automatically initialized if

- it's a class/struct instance in which the default constructor initializes all primitive types; like `MyClass instance;`
- you use array initializer syntax, e.g. `int a[10] = {}` (all zeroed) or `int a[10] = {1,2};` (all zeroed except the first two items: `a[0] == 1` and `a[1] == 2`)
- same applies to non-aggregate classes/structs, e.g. MyClass instance = {}; (more information on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default/1069634#1069634))
- it's a global/extern variable
- the variable is defined `static` (no matter if inside a function or in global/namespace scope) - *thanks Jerry*

Never trust on a variable of a plain type (int, long, ...) being automatically initialized! It might happen in languages like C#, but not in C & C++.

Comment: The first point is a bit inaccurate. It'll be automatically initialized if it is a non-POD type. :)

Comment: Variables with static storage duration of "plain type" are also initialized to zero (or a null pointer, in the case of pointers). This would be either something declared `static` inside a function, or something declared at namespace scope (i.e. outside any function).

Comment: In point two, may I suggest you explicitly state what `a[0]` and `a[1]` (preferable referring to them as such) will be initialised to, if anything.

Comment: My 2 cents - regarding last point 'the variable is defined static' - variable may have static storage duration but does not have to be defined as static (ie. with 'static' keyword ). Just having any primitive type in global scope makes it have 'static storage duration' hence you do not need 'static' keyword in global scope to make it happen. Only in local scope you need 'static' keyword' to make local variable have 'static storage duration'.

Answer (score 11):

`int` doesn't initialize to zero. When you say `int i;`, all you're doing is reserving space for an integer. The value at that location is not initialized. That's only done with you say `int i = 0;` (or `int i = 5;` in which case the value is initialized to 5). Eitherway, it's good practice to initialize a variable to some known value. Otherwise, `i` holds whatever random value was at that memory location when space was reserved for it. This is why the `cout` prints out a random value.

Default values depend on the implementation of the language. Some languages will initialize it to some "sane" value (like 0 perhaps). As a rule of thumb, I always initialize a variable to some sensible value (unless I know that I am going to initialize it to something else *for sure* before I use it). As I mentioned before, it's unwise to *assume* that the value is going to be something sane. It may or may not be (depending on the language, or the implementation of the interpreter/compiler for that language).

Answer (score 4):

This post says it best: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?p=1528247&postcount=10

> There's no "default" constructor for
>   non-class types, but there is default
>   (zero) initialization. Unfortunately,
>   for braindead compatibility with C,
>   the default initialization is NOT done
>   for POD types in the following
>   circumstances:
>
> Naked (i.e., declared without
>   initializers) variables local to a
>   class or function.
>
> dynamically allocated instances.
>
> However, in other places (notably
>   static variables) and in the case of
>   anything given the empty initializer
>   paramters (when that is valid), gets
>   the default (zero) initialization.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's due to "brainded compability with C", I think it has more to do with C++'s "don't pay for what you don't use" philosophy.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, automatic variables are undefined until they are explicitly given a value. Perhaps you are thinking of C# or other .Net languages, or Java.

Answer (score 4):

See section 4.9.5 Initialization of The C++ Programming Language.

Depending on whether your variable is local, static, user-defined or const default initialization can happen.

Because you're using POD (Plain Old Datatypes), the auto variable is not initialized to any default value.

Answer (score 4):

To force initialization of a POD (which `int` is), you can use copy initializer syntax:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int i = int();
  int j;

  std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl;
  // warning: undefined behavior
  std::cout << "j: " << j << std::endl;
}
```

This is falls under "only pay for what you use". If you are going to subsequently assign a value to the variable, or possibly not use it at all, there's no reason to do the work of initializing it. To get that, you have to explicitly ask that that work be done.

Comment: this does not work for `unsigned int`s or `long long` or similar types which consist of more than one word in GCC, however it does work in MSVC, related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144012/explicit-type-conversion-and-multiple-simple-type-specifiers

Answer (score 3):

Different operating systems ( i.e. OS X vs. Ubuntu Linux ) will react differently to uninitialized versus initialized variables in C++. In my experience, the OS X version of  gcc will compile and print out 2 for both versions of the code below. Where as if I'm working on an Ubuntu Linux machine the first code block will print out whatever happened to be at the memory location the variable references ( + 2 after the loop ).

```
    int c;

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        c++;
    }

    cout << c << endl;
```

Where as, they will all give you the same results for:

```
    int c = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        c++;
    }

    cout << c << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Local variables aren't initialized unless you do it yourself. What you're seeing is whatever garbage was on the stack before your method was called.

Answer (score 2):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an
>   object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value.

Par. 8.5, section 11 of a recent C++0x draft N3092.pdf,

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/

Answer (score 0):

Although your recent discovery may be unwelcome (because you may need to initialise some variables other languages would have taken care of), it can mean fewer cpu cycles, and thus faster code.

Answer (score -1):

Here `int i;` is a automatic variable which must be initialize manually.
auto variable doesn't initialize automatically in c and c++.

If you want compiler to initialize it, then you need to use following things,

declare `i` as static variable.

`static int i;`  // zero assign to the i by compiler.

declare `i` as global variable[outside the main()].