# How to safely check for null pointers

Tags: c++

(Using visual studio 2010)

I have a simple `returnLength()` function for a list, defined simply as

```
int returnLength() 
{
    if (!next) return 1;
    else return 1 + next->returnLength();
}
```

next is a pointer to another node in the list.  When checking the if statement to check if next is valid, Visual Studio is throwing a runtime error citing Access violation.  This error is occurring several calls deep into the recursion tree.

What is the recommended way to check whether a pointer exists?

Comment: The *next* member isn't the problem, *this* is probably null.  Check the object reference in the caller.

Comment: On the side: What is the length of an empty list, 0 or 1? `returnLength()` seem to return 1.

Comment: All these people saying that `this` is probably null are wrong and not paying attention -- `this` cannot possibly be null at any but the first level of recursion. Rather, `this` (which was `next` of the previous node) is *some other* invalid value, because `next` of the last node wasn't initialized.

Answer (score 4):

That is a valid way.  What's likely happening here is that `this` is `NULL` and hence you're getting an access violation trying to read `next` off of `NULL` pointer.  You need to check for `NULL` at the callsite to `returnLength`

Comment: Very interesting.  The runtime error is occurring several layers deep within this recursive call... So it seems like this should be catching itself..

Comment: @pbj: the plague of undefined behavior, anything can happen, so most of the times it looks like it's working fine for a while...

Comment: Wrong answer. `this` (which was `next` from the previous node) is obviously some uninitialized value *other than* `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

The code you've shown is valid.  What is most likely happening is that this function is being called through an invalid `this` pointer.

Comment: An invalid this pointer shouldn't be happening 10 recursive calls deep though, should it?  (This error is occurring several calls deep into the call stack on this function alone.  No threading)

Comment: It might be that the final pointer in your list is not NULL but an uninitialized (random) value.  Or potentially a pointer to an object that has already been freed.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the last node in the list has an invalid value for `next` - it should be `NULL`. Is `next` definitely initialised to `NULL` in the default constructor for this class? If it isn't then that might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio isn't throwing the runtime error, but I know what you mean.

We need a little more code than this though. Is return length a method of your class list? Where is `next` declared? Where is it initialized? Most likely, `next` is an uninitialized pointer or a pointer to deallocated memory. At the very least, it is a pointer to an invalid location, thus the access violation error.

Initialize `next` appropriately. Checking if a pointer is null is the only appropriate mechanism for pointer validity.

Edit: It sounds like you're unfamiliar with pointer validity in general. You can not check if a pointer points to a valid location. You can only check if a pointer points to the universally invalid location `null` or `0`. So... if you don't have a pointer pointing to something, you should initialize or set it as `null` or `0`, that is its purpose.

Comment: The code I provided is checking the validity of the next pointer, is it not?

Comment: It is checking if next points to anything at all. I'll revise my answer to give a little more information.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your description, it appears that `next` is not null, but still invalid. E.g. if your `ListNode::RemoveNextNode()` function had a bug where it did delete the next node but failed to change `this->next`. In that case you have a pointer to deallocated memory. You can't test for that; you have to make sure it doesn't happen.

In general, of course, the solution is to use `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ variables are not guaranteed to be initialized with anything sensible.  If you create a variable of:
    MyType* next;

The `next` pointer can be `NULL` or it can be any other value.  This value will be junk, but will not be zero and will cause your access violation.

To guarantee that `next` is `NULL` you must ensure that it is set to `NULL` in the object's constructor.

See [Variable initialization in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218254/variable-initialization-in-c) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T_TYPE, typename T_RET, typename T_DELETE_POLICY>
class ToRef: public boost::tuple<T_TYPE*const&, T_RET, T_DELETE_POLICY>
{
public:
    ToRef<T_TYPE, T_RET, T_DELETE_POLICY>(T_TYPE*const& p_type, const T_DELETE_POLICY delete_policy)
    : boost::tuple<T_TYPE*const&, T_RET, T_DELETE_POLICY>(p_type, p_type!=NULL, delete_policy)
{
}
};

template <typename T_TYPE>
class ToRef<T_TYPE, bool, bool>: public boost::tuple<T_TYPE*const&, bool, bool>
{
public:
    explicit ToRef<T_TYPE, bool, bool>(T_TYPE*const& p_type, const bool delete_policy)
    :boost::tuple<T_TYPE*const&, bool, bool>(p_type, p_type!=NULL, delete_policy)
{
}

~ToRef()
{
    //delete policy
    if (get<2>())
    {
        if (NULL != get<0>())
            delete get<0>();
        const_cast<T_TYPE*&>(get<0>())= NULL;
    }
}

private:
    ToRef<T_TYPE, bool, bool>(ToRef<T_TYPE, bool, bool>& copy){};
    ToRef<T_TYPE, bool, bool>& operator = (ToRef<T_TYPE, bool, bool>& rhs){};

public:
    bool is_valid(void) const
    {
        //validity of the pointer.
        return get<1>();
    }

    T_TYPE& r_get(void) const
    {
        if (is_valid())
            return *get<0>();
        throw std::string("Invalid Pointer");
    }
protected:
    T_TYPE*const & p_get(void) const
    {
        return get<0>();
    }
};

//use it to safely access the pointers.
//if block is an overhead here.
#define safe_access_start(Ref) if (Ref.is_valid()) {
#define safe_access_end } 

//faster mode but unsafe. exception handling takes care of preventing 
//unhandled exception to cascade to the top.
#define fast_access_start try {
#define fast_access_end }catch (std::string s_exception){ TRACE("%s, %d, 
   %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, LPCTSTR(s_exception.c_str()));}
```

> In your case it might work like this

```
 int returnLength() 
    {
        if (!next) return 1;

        sa::ToRef<Stest, bool, bool> testRef(sTest, false);

        safe_access_start(testRef)
        return 1 + testRef.r_get().returnLength();
        safe_access_end

        return 1;

    }
```

Comment: It is good practice to include some explanation to an answer, not just code. I suggest to add one.