# C++ strlen(ch) and sizeof(ch) strlen

Tags: c++, c

I have this code:

```
int main()
{
    char ch[15];
    cout<<strlen(ch)<<endl; //7
    cout<<sizeof(ch)<<endl; //15
    return 0;
}
```

Why does `strlen(ch)` give different result even if it is empty `char` array?

Comment: It's not empty. It's loaded with uninitialized junk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ch` is a local variable and local variables are not initialized. So your assumption that it is an empty string is not correct. Its filled with junk. It was just a co-incidence that a `\0` character was found after 7 junk characters and hence `strlen` returned 7.

You can do something like these to ensure an empty string-

```
char ch[15]={0};
ch[0]='\0`;
strcpy(ch,"");
```

Here's a similar thread for more reading

[Variable initialization in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218254/variable-initialization-in-c)

Comment: static locals are default-initialized ;) Or was it value-initialized? Damnit, I never get this right.

Comment: static locals are zero-initialized before program startup; they are then default-initialized (for object types) when first encountered.

Answer (score 6):

Your code has *undefined behavior* because you are reading the uninitialized values of your array with `strlen`. If you want a determinate result from `strlen` you must initialize (or assign to) your array.

E.g.

```
char ch[15] = "Hello, world!";
```

or

```
char ch[15] = {};
```

`sizeof` will give the size of its operand, as the size of `char` is one by definition the size of a `char[15]` will always be 15.

`strlen` gives the length of a null terminated string which is the offset of the first `char` with value `0` in a given `char` array. For a call to `strlen` to be valid, the argument to must actually point to a null terminated string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
strlen(ch);
```

`strlen` counts the number of chars, untill hitting the `\0` symbol. Here, `ch` is non-initialized, so `strlen` could return *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

As for the result from `strlen`, in your case you have an uninitialized `char` array, and so `strlen` only *happens* to yield *7*: there must be a null character at array element 8, but this code could give different results for `strlen` every time.

Always initialize strings, it's easy enough with an array: `char str[15] = {0};`

`sizeof` is an operator used to get the size of a variable or a data type, or the number of bytes occupied by an array, **not** the length of a C string; don't expect `strlen` and `strcpy` to be interchangeable, or even comparable in any useful way.

For instance:

```
int main()
{
    char str[15] = "only 13 chars";

    cout << "strlen: " << strlen(str) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof: " << sizeof(str) << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
strlen: 13
sizeof: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

> Returns the length of str.
>
> The length of a C string is determined by the terminating
>   null-character: A C string is as long as the amount of characters
>   between the beginning of the string and the terminating null
>   character.

`sizeof` returns number of bytes (15). Your array is filled by garbage, so, strlen can returns any number. Correct example is

```
int main()
{
    char ch[15] = {0};
    cout<<strlen(ch)<<endl; //0
    cout<<sizeof(ch)<<endl; //15
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `sizeof` and `strlen` in C++:

1) `sizeof` is a **operator**, `strlen` is a **function**;

2) The return type of `sizeof` is `size_t`，and it is defined (typedef) as `unsigned int` in its header; **It gets the byte size of the memory allocation which can maximize to accommodate this object to be created in memory**;

3) `sizeof` can use **type** as a parameter, while `strlen` can only use char pointer (`char*`) as a pointer, and it must be ended as '`\0`'; 
`sizeof` can also use function as a parameter, for instance:

```
short f() {return 100;} 
std::cout << "sizeof(f()): " << sizeof(f()) << std::endl;
//The result will be sizeof(short), which is 2.
```

4) If char array is a parameter, it will not be degraded by `sizeof`, while `strlen` will degrade it as a char pointer;

5) The result of `strlen` will be calculated in the **run time**, not **compilation time**, `strlen` is used to get the real size of the content of a string (string, char array, char pointer) until the '`\0`', not the real size of memory allocation. Most of the compiler will calculate the result of `sizeof` in the **compilation time**, no matter the parameter is type or variable, that is why `sizeof(x)` can be used to decide the dimension of an array:

```
char str[20]="0123456789"; 
int a=strlen(str); //a=10; 
int b=sizeof(str); //while b=20;
```

7) If the parameter of `sizeof` is a **type**, then parentheses are **mandatory**, while if the parameter is a **variable**, parentheses are **optional**, because **`sizeof` is an operator not a function**;

8) When you use a structured **type** or **variable** as a parameter, `sizeof` will return its **real size**, when you use a **static array**, `sizeof` will return the **array size**. But `sizeof` operator cannot return the size of an array which is created **dynamically** or **externally**. Because sizeof is a **compilation time operator**.

Here is an example of sizeof and strlen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

short f1 ()
{
  return 100;
}

int f2 ()
{
  return 1000;
}

int main()
{
  char* char_star = "0123456789";
  // char_star is a char pointer, sizeof will return the pointer size allocated in memory: depends on your machine
  std::cout << "sizeof(char_star):" << sizeof(char_star) << std::endl;
  // *char_star is the first element of the string, it is a char, sizeof will return the char size allocated in memory: depends on your machine, normally is 1
  std::cout << "sizeof(*char_star):" << sizeof(*char_star) << std::endl;
  // char_star is a char pointer, strlen will return the real size of the string until '\0': 10
  std::cout << "strlen(char_star):" << strlen(char_star) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  char char_array[] = "0123456789";
  // char_array is a char array, sizeof will return the array size allocated in memory, with a '\0' at the end: 10 + 1
  std::cout << "sizeof(char_array):" << sizeof(char_array) << std::endl;
  // *char_array is the first element of the array, it is a char, sizeof will return the char size allocated in memory: depends on your machine, normally is 1
  std::cout << "sizeof(*char_array):" << sizeof(*char_array) << std::endl;
  // char_array is a char array, strlen will return the real size of the string until '\0': 10
  std::cout << "strlen(char_array):" << strlen(char_array) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  char_array_fixed[100] = "0123456789";
  // char_array_fixed is a char array with fixed size, sizeof will return the array size allocated in memory: 100
  std::cout << "sizeof(char_array_fixed):" << sizeof(char_array_fixed) << std::endl;
  // *char_array_fixed is the first element of the array, it is a char, sizeof will return the char size allocated in memory: depends on your machine, normally is 1
  std::cout << "sizeof(*char_array_fixed):" << sizeof(*char_array_fixed) << std::endl;
  // *char_array_fixed is a char array with fixed size, strlen will return the real content size of the string until '\0': 10
  std::cout << "strlen(char_array_fixed):" << strlen(char_array_fixed) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  int int_array[100] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  // int_array is a int array with fixed size, sizeof will return the array size allocated in memory: 100
  std::cout << "sizeof(int_array):" << sizeof(int_array) << std::endl;
  // *int_array is the first element of the array, it is an int, sizeof will return the int size allocated in memory: depends on your machine, normally is 4
  std::cout << "sizeof(*int_array):" << sizeof(*int_array) << std::endl;
  // int_array is a int array with fixed size, strlen will throw exception 
  //std::cout << "strlen(int_array):" << strlen(int_array) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  char char_array2[] = {'a', 'b', '3'};
  // char_array2 is a char array, sizeof will return the array size allocated in memory: 3
  std::cout << "sizeof(char_array2):" << sizeof(char_array2) << std::endl;
  // *char_array2 is the first element of the array, it is a char, sizeof will return the char size allocated in memory: depends on your machine, normally is 1
  std::cout << "sizeof(*char_array2):" << sizeof(*char_array2) << std::endl;
  // *char_array2 is a char array, strlen will return the real content size of the string until '\0': 3
  std::cout << "strlen(char_array2):" << strlen(char_array2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  char char_array3[] = {"abc"};
  // char_array3 is a char array, sizeof will return the array size allocated in memory, with a '\0' at the end : 3 + 1
  std::cout << "sizeof(char_array3):" << sizeof(char_array3) << std::endl;
  // *char_array3 is the first element of the array, it is a char, sizeof will return the char size allocated in memory: depends on your machine, normally is 1
  std::cout << "sizeof(*char_array3):" << sizeof(*char_array3) << std::endl;
  // *char_array3 is a char array, strlen will return the real content size of the string until '\0': 3
  std::cout << "strlen(char_array3):" << strlen(char_array3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::string str = {'a', 'b', '3', '\0', 'X'};
  // str is a string, sizeof will return the string size allocated in memory (string is a wrapper, can be considered as a special structure with a pointer to the real content): depends on your machine, normally is 32
  std::cout << "str:" << str << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sizeof(str):" << sizeof(str) << std::endl;
  // *str means nothing, sizeof will throw exeption
  //std::cout << "sizeof(*str):" << sizeof(*str) << std::endl;
  // str is a string, strlen will return the real content size of the string until '\0': 3
  std::cout << "strlen(str):" << strlen(str.c_str()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // sizeof is an operation, if the parameter is a type, parentheses are mandatory
  std::cout << "sizof(int):" << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
  // sizeof is an operation, if the parameter is a variable, parentheses are optional
  std::cout << "sizof char_star:" << sizeof char_star << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sizof char_array:" << sizeof char_array << std::endl;
  // sizeof is an operation, can take a function as parameter
  std::cout << "sizeof(f()): " << sizeof(f1()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sizeof(f()): " << sizeof(f2()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Wrong on several counts. 1) "it is defined (typedef) as unsigned int in its header"; not necessarily the case. 2) strlen is not *necessarily* runtime. 3) What do you mean by *degraded*?

Comment: 1.) the return type of  sizeof is size_t, and size_t is an unsigned integer (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t); 2) I do not say strlen is necessarily runtime, from the example I tested and this question, it is this case; 3) degrated means when you pass a char array (such like the code example I provided: char_array), strlen will treated it as a char pointer.

Comment: unsigned integer is a superset of unsigned int. An answer like this needs to be pretty faultless. Do fix and I’ll convert the downvote to an upvote. Decay is the conventional term on 3.

Comment: I think most of people can understand my point, you can keep your downvote, it does not matter for me if you can be happy with this. I just want to help people to understand the issue they faced, not need to quibble for each single word. If they need to understand size_t details, then they will check it, it is out of the scope of this question.