# Dynamic character array not giving correct string length?

Tags: c++, memory-management, char

I would like to have a dynamic character array who's length equals the loop iteration.

```
char* output;
for (short i=0; i<2; i++){
    output = new char[i+1];
    printf("string length: %d\n",strlen(output));
    delete[] output;
}
```

But `strlen` is returning 16, where I would expect it to be 1 and 2.

Comment: `new` operator does not guarantee the memory block's bytes will be _zero_ed.

Comment: To initialize the data use `output = new char[i+1]();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ strlen(ch) and sizeof(ch) strlen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930366/c-strlench-and-sizeofch-strlen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The newly allocated memory pointed to by `output` is not initialized:  it may have any contents.

`strlen` requires its argument to be a pointer to a null-terminated string, which `output` is not, because it hasn't been initialized.  The call `strlen(output)` causes your program to exhibit undefined behavior because it reads this uninitialized memory.  Any result is possible.

Comment: So, I assume `output` will still have the right memory size, despite `strlen`'s undefined behavior?

Comment: `output` will point to an array of i + 1 `char` objects, yes. The `strlen` function does not compute the size of an array, it computes the length of a null-terminated string

Answer (score 0):

strlen expects to find NULL at the end of the string, it counts all the caracters until it finds a 0
you should change the line to `output = new char[i+1]();` to initialize the chars to 0

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are null terminated. `strlen()` returns the bytes counted until that null termination is found.

`new` operator does not guarantee the memory block's bytes will be _zero_ed.

You could use `calloc()`, which zero'es all the bytes of the block it allocates, or you need to do `memset(output, 0, i+1)` after allocating with `new` operator.

Comment: Lets not resort to C voodoo in a C++ question. You can initialize with new using: `output = new char[i+1]();`

Comment: Yeah, did not think of using an empty constructor, yet, `strlen()` is in `<cstring>`.