# Should T() initialize member variables to zero?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initialization

I am fairly new to C++, have written a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Point
{  
public:
    int X, Y;

    int dis()
    {
        std::cout << X << Y << std::endl;
        return X;
    }

    int operator=(const Point&)
    { 
        int dat = 3;
        return dat;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
    Point p2 = Point();
    p2.dis();
    return 0;
}
```

Here `p2` should initialize both class `Point` variables `x` and `y` to zero right? But instead when I do `p2.dis()`, I am getting `x` and `y` intialized to some random values.

and in the following case tSum = 0, even if "T" is of type class.

```
template<typename T>
double GetAverage(T tArray[], int nElements)
{
    T tSum = T(); // tSum = 0
    for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < nElements; ++nIndex)
    {
        tSum += tArray[nIndex];
    }

    // Whatever type of T is, convert to double
    return double(tSum) / nElements;
}
```

how is this different ?

Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: Where do templates come in play? You never use `Item`. As stated, the code should work as you describe it.

Comment: You could use **in class initializers** to make your code more readable. Then if the value is not the one you set, you'd only have to search for the place where the defaults are overriden

Comment: VC++ has some bugs related to value-initialization.

Comment: sorry, not using template class at the moment. But I have this issue before I reach to that step. Here I expect p2.dis() to output X=0 and Y=0, but instead it is outputting X=-858993460 and Y=-858993460

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable initialization in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218254/variable-initialization-in-c)

Comment: @MorphingDragon that's substantially different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules of the language requires

```
Point p2 = Point();
```

to *value-initialize* `p2`. Since `Point` doesn't have a user-defined constructor, value-initialization includes zero-initialization and both `p2.X` and `p2.Y` [should be zero](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13268b6fe679d9b3).

You are seeing a Visual C++ bug (-858993460 is `0xCCCCCCCC`, which VC++ fills uninitialized variables with in debug mode). The workaround is to provide a default constructor to `Point` that explicitly initializes both member variables to zero.

Comment: I agree, can be a visualc++ bug.

Comment: Just curious: Does `Point p2 = Point()` mean a default-initialization (`Point()`) which means default-initialization for its non-static data members which for integers is value-initialization, followed by copy-initialization for `p2`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `Point()` is value-initialization, not default-initialization. Pre-C++11 this means value-initializing the data members, which for `int` means zero-initialization; post-C++11 this zero-initializes the `Point` itself. The whole thing constructs a value-initialized temporary and then copy-initializes `p2` from that, but the temporary is elided in any decent compiler.

Comment: What does it mean to zero-initialize the `Point` itself? You mean fill its bits with zero? Also, where does default-initialization come into this?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, all the bits, including padding. If `Point`'s default constructor were nontrivial, then it would be called after the zero-initialization, but otherwise default-initialization doesn't really come into play.

Comment: *The rules of the language since 2003

Answer (score 2):

You just need constructor with default values for both fields:

```
Point() : X(), Y()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++98 this code leaves `p2.X` and `p2.Y` uninitialized.

This is because `Point` has a user-declared copy-assignment operator, therefore `Point` is what's known as a *non-POD* class.

In C++98, `Point()` for a non-POD class always calls the default constructor (even if implicitly declared); and the implicitly-declared default constructor does not initialize any class members.

In C++03 initialization got a major rework and *value initialization* was introduced. `Point()` was now value initialization, which means that the default constructor is called *only if it was user-declared*.

If you didn't declare a default constructor then the class members are value-initialized even if the class is non-POD. So `p2.X` and `p2.Y` must be initialized to `0` in C++03 (and later).

---

Nowdays we like to pretend C++98 never existed, but apparently MSVC++ still follows it in some initialization cases. (Latest versions of C++Builder 32-bit also use C++98-style initialization in this case too).

Comment: Would be interesting to see if MSVC++ does zero-initialize them if you remove your copy-assignment operator (which is what C++98 specifies - PODs have members zero-intiialized).