# what is the value after declaring a pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

For example, after I declare a node struct

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node *next;
}
int main(){
    node *root = new node;
}
```

I know it would automatically initialize `root->data` to 0, but what happens to `root->next`. Is it initialized to nullptr or what?

Comment: In the code above, neither `data` or `next` would be initialized to anything definite.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2218254/1601448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those members will be initialized as it stands. If you want them to be set to their "default values" `0` and `nullptr` respectively, you can use something like this:

```
struct node {
    int data {};
    node *next {};
};
```

Now, in every new instance, you will have `data == 0` and `next == nullptr`. This C++11 feature is called *"default member initializer"*.

---

If you cannot use C++11, you can achieve this value initialization either via

```
node* root = new node();  // <- Note the parenthesis
```

as [@vsoftco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093378/vsoftco) pointed out or via [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) like this:

```
node root = {};
```

I would however prefer the variant at the top of this post if possible as it yields less opportunity for mistakes.

Comment: Or you can alternatively (C++98) use `node* root = new node();` This *will* value-initialize the struct.