# size_t different default value when running through VS2013 debugger vs CommandLine

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Running the following code via the visual studio debugger executes successfully. The "count" variable will be default initialized to 0.

If I run via the command line, i get random behaviour and my EXPECT_EQ( ... ) fails.

```
size_t expectedCount = actual.length() - expected.length();
position += 12;
size_t count;
for (size_t i = position ; i < actual.length(); ++i) {
    if (actual.at(i) == 'a')
        ++count;
}

EXPECT_EQ(expectedCount , count);
```

I'm assuming this is because Visual studio gives me a clean stack (everything is 0) whereas the commandline has lingering garbage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a function scope, the syntax `size_t count;` will not initialize a variable. Use `size_t count{};`

For more info on initialization, see
[Variable initialization in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218254/variable-initialization-in-c).

Comment: You're assuming C++ not C.  Is there a difference?

Comment: ANSI C99 will initialize auto scope (function scope, non-static, non-thread-local) variables to an "indeterminate" value (garbage) in the absence of an initializer expression. Reference [ISO/IEC 9899:TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) See section 6.7.8 paragraph 10. _If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate._

Answer (score 1):

Your Debug build may be setting count to 0 due to the nature of that build configuration but not in Release build.  You need to initialize **count** to zero.  Always initialize variables.