# Why is local variable being initialised by default?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

In section 9.2 of the book *The C++ Programming Language*, Bjarne Stroustrup wrote:

> Note that a variable defined without an initializer in the global or a namespace scope is initialized by default. This is not the case for local variables or objects created on the free store.

But the following program prints a value of 0:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't it be returning some kind of error?

I use `g++` to compile.

Comment: It's *not* initialized. It's value will be *indeterminate*. For you it happens to be zero, for someone else it can be some other seemingly random value. And using indeterminate values in C++, even just reading them like you do, is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: You have a slight logical fallacy there. Nothing makes 0 any less random than others values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is the memory allocated as soon as the variable is declared or after it's assigned?

Comment: But there is no assignment being made. The value of `x` will in reality just be what happens to be in the memory that is now occupied by `x`. You don't know where this memory is located, or what the contents will be. All you know is that there is `sizeof x` bytes allocated somewhere for the variable.

Comment: Never ever compile anything without the `-Wall` compiler option. A good starter set is `-Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors`, highly recommended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable initialization in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218254/variable-initialization-in-c)

Comment: @xskxzr I think mine is specific to local variables. The other OP didn't mention that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can't this be known by via a pointer to that variable. I just tried and it gave me some address.

Comment: The variable `x` have a location. But the contents of that location is indeterminate. You need to learn the difference between a variables location and its value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't remember where but I read that memory is not allocated when a variable is declared, it's allocated when it's first assigned. Is this wrong? If not, why is memory allocated to this variable.

Comment: Okay, then you need to learn the difference between *declaration* and *definition*. A variable gets space in memory with its *definition*.

Comment: I suggest you get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But here I declared the variable and didn't define it. Right?

Comment: Since local variables are not defined without an initializer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167041/discussion-between-lashit-jain-and-some-programmer-dude).

Comment: A *declaration* is you telling the compiler that something exists somewhere. A *definition* is telling the compiler that something exists right here. A definition may also be a declaration, and in your case for the variable `x` you have both. Really, don't just guess, get a good book.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Since local variables are not defined without an initializer, doesn't it mean in my case it's not a definition, just a declaration?

Comment: No you're still misunderstand me! A definition doesn't need an initialization. Doesn't matter when or where the definition is. Stop just guessing and get a book!

Comment: Don't "A definition doesn't need an initialization" in local variable's context and "Local Variables are not defined without an initializer" contradict? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @LashitJain: Why do you keep ignoring the "get a book" part? C++ is an incredibly complex programming language. You cannot learn it via Stack Overflow comments.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I am reading a book as specified in the question. But the statement that someprogrammerdude gave and the one I read in the book contradict. Therefore I'm asking the question (the comment one).

Comment: Nevertheless, I'll read more from the book and try figuring this out. If not possible I'll raise a question later. Thank you guys for the help and insightful comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But the following program prints a value of 0 on my terminal.

It has undefined behaviour because the `cout` line tries to read from an uninitialised `int`. Any output you see, and in fact any behaviour at all, is not guaranteed.

> Shouldn't it be returning some kind of error?

No, that's not how undefined behaviour works. You may or may not see an error.

Answer (score 5):

**`x` is uninitialized, so your snippet actually has an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).**

---

> Shouldn't it be returning some kind of error?

**`g++` doesn't warn of uninitialized values by default.**

You need the `-Wuninitialized` option if you want your compiler to show a warning:

```
g++ -Wuninitialized your_file.c
```

You should probably use the `-Wall` option instead to enable this warning alongside lots of other useful warnings.

More information on warning options [**here**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't it be returning some kind of error?

No, it should not, but this error is detectable by [**Valgrind**](http://valgrind.org/):

```
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes ./a.out
==4950== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4950== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4950== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4950== Command: ./a.out
==4950== 
==4950== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4950==    at 0x4F4444A: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (locale_facets.tcc:874)
==4950==    by 0x4F504C4: put (locale_facets.h:2371)
==4950==    by 0x4F504C4: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (ostream.tcc:73)
==4950==    by 0x40076D: main (t.cpp:5)
==4950==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4950==    at 0x400757: main (t.cpp:3)
==4950==
```

This part of Valgrind output clearly states that:

```
==4950==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4950==    at 0x400757: main (t.cpp:3)
==4950==
```