# Is struct member pointers automatically initialized to zero?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, gcc-warning

If I have the following struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int *a;
    int *b;
};
```

And initializes it like this:

```
int some_var;
MyStruct s{
    .a = &some_var
};
```

can I be sure `s.b` will be initialized to `nullptr`?

EDIT:

Full compiling code, tested with g++ 7.3.0:

```
// test.cpp
struct MyStruct {
    int *a;
    int *b;
};

int main()
{
    int some_var;
    MyStruct s{
        .a = &some_var
    };
}
```

If I print the variable values at this sample, b is indeed 0. But I want to know if this behavior is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: That doesn't look like `C++`.

Comment: You can be sure it's a syntax error.

Comment: g++ prints this error message: `warning: C++ designated initializers only available with -std=c++2a or -std=gnu++2a` anybody knows whether this is planned and where I could read the draft/proposal? E: Found something: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0329r0.pdf

Comment: @NeilButterworth Compiles with g++ 7.3, it is standard C++11.

Comment: It is _not_ standard C++11. The fact that GCC compiles it proves nothing - GCC compiles all sorts of non-standard stuff. Use the `-pedantic` option to filter some of it out.

Comment: "Is struct member pointers automatically initialized to zero?" - No.

Comment: `s.b` will not be initialized.  If it was a global variable, it would be zero-initialized.
Some compilers zero-initialize variables when compiling with debug options, though.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It doesn't mean it isn't, either. But I am pretty sure it is standard. It also compiles with clang with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: It is NOT part of Standard C++ 11 (or indeed of any of the later standards up to this date).

Comment: Why not just initialize them to `nullptr` explicitly? Like this: `int *a = nullptr;`

Comment: C++ guarantees you nothing in this case. The implementation may zero the stack, assuming it's using a stack, at start-up and you're taking advantage of that to get null pointers in your sample code. You cannot count on this behaviour. By the way, " warning: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers [-Wpedantic]". My understanding (thank you @NeilButterworth )  is that support may be added in C++ 20.

Comment: Some helpful reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Comment: And probably duplicate: [Variable initialization in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218254/variable-initialization-in-c)

Comment: @user4581301 it kinda very special case,  and documentation on GCC should be referred instead of C++ standard.. because this is a GCC feature. I  vote to remove c++11 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, this is C99 syntax, which is not supported by C++11 standard, but supported by GCC. GCC documentation states so that that omitted field members are implicitly initialized the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Alternate syntax would be

```
MyStruct s{
        a: &some_var
    };
```

If the same field is initialized multiple times, it would be initialized with the value from the last initialization. If such initialization causes side-effect, it is unspecified whether the side effect happens or not. GCC discards them, only *last* initialization happens.

Here is C++11 compatible initialization:

```
MyStruct s { &some_var };  // second field would be initialized as one with static duration
```

GCC would issue a warning about missing initializers in both cases.