# Constructor-style casting in function call parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

I don't understand why the following code fails to compile when using constructor-style casting:

```
template<typename T> void foo(const T& t){}

int main(){
  foo(unsigned char(0));
}
```

The errors are:

- `error: expected primary-expression before ‘unsigned’` for gcc.
- `error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction` for clang

However these three syntaxes are correct:

```
template<typename T> void foo(const T& t){}

int main(){
  // c-style cast
  foo((unsigned char)0);

  // without unsigned
  foo(char(0));

  // aliased unsigned char
  typedef unsigned char uchar;
  foo(uchar(0));
}
```

So the space in the type is obviously to blame here.

I thought it might be somehow related to our old friend [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), so I tried the [uniform initialization syntax](http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init), which is supposed to get rid of this sort of ambiguities, but no luck:

```
template<typename T> void foo(const T& t){}

int main(){
  foo(unsigned char{0});
}
```

But still:

- `error: expected primary-expression before ‘unsigned’` for gcc.
- `error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction` for clang

So my question is why is it not allowed to have a type containing a space in function-style casts? It doesn't look ambiguous to me.

***note***: I know I can write `foo<unsigned char>(0)`, but it doesn't answer the question ;)

Comment: For what it's worth `int main()
{
   unsigned char c = unsigned char(0);
}
` doesn't compile either using g++.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance—but is not ``(unsigned char)(0)`` what the OP wants? Or does it have different semantics? (Simple yes/no answer is sufficient, I’ll dig into it deeper when you tell me it’s different by myself)

Comment: Also, both the constructs are successfully compiled by Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Yours is a C-style casting. They are equivalent, but I was wondering if that was not a compiler bug, which would be bad. There are multiple semantically equivalent syntax, but I don't know why some are not valid.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: The question is about _functional notation_ specifically, which that is not.

Comment: I'm retracting my close vote; this _is_ a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963396/gcc-doesnt-like-c-style-casts-with-spaces, but that question doesn't look as good and the answers sort of skirt around the issue. I'm going to take the unusual step of voting _that_ one as a dup of _this_ one.

Comment: The problem is that someone somehow thought clever to introduce blanks in type names at some point in C (`signed` and `unsigned` with various combinations of `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long`). It was a bad idea, and now we live with it...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> `[C++11: 5.2.3/1]:` A *simple-type-specifier* (7.1.6.2) or *typename-specifier* (14.6) followed by a parenthesized *expression-list* constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list. *[..]*

Examining the grammar, we see that the only way to get `unsigned char` from the *simple-type-specifier* production is by concatenating two of them.

As evidence debunking the rumour that table 10 is stating the contrary, which I may myself  have started a short while ago (:P), the table heading says "specifier(s)" (note the optional plural), and refer to the below passage:

> `[C++11: 5.2.3/2]:` *[..]* Table 10 summarizes the valid **combinations** of *simple-type-specifiers* and the types they specify. <sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup>

Now, combining *simple-type-specifiers* is allowed in some cases:

> `[C++11: 7.1.6.2/3]:` When multiple *simple-type-specifiers* are allowed, they can be freely intermixed with other *decl-specifiers* in any order. *[..]*

… but there's no indication that this is the case with functional notation, which clearly states "**a** *simple-type-specifier*" — singular.

**Therefore GCC is correct, and Visual Studio is wrong.**

As for *why* this is the case... well, I don't know. I suspect we could come up with some ambiguous edge case, but [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923854/casey) makes a good point in the comments below that allowing this would be inconsistent with function call syntax, since names of functions cannot have spaces in them.

Comment: I thought it might be a compiler bug too (especially the uniform initialization syntax), but from both clang and gcc that seems unlikely. Thanks for the pointers to the standard, I will check that out.

Comment: @Thibaut: I'm not aware of any compiler that accepts `unsigned char` with functional notation (though I haven't tried VS); but having looked into it from the standard's POV for the first time just now, I honestly can't explain _why_ that is.

Comment: a comment to your linked post, is uniform initialization considered a type of casting? I thought it was just a strongly typed initialization.

Comment: @Thibaut VS2013 is compiling your code without any complaints. That's gotta be a first, where VS gets something right while clang and gcc don't. I think this answer is correct, because *Table 10* under *[dcl.type.simple]* lists `unsigned char` as a *simple-type-specifier*.

Comment: `[C++11: 5.2.3/3]:` Similarly, a _simple-type-specifier_ or _typename-specifier_ followed by a _braced-init-list_ creates a temporary object of the specified type _direct-list-initialized_ (8.5.4) with the specified _braced-init-list_, and its value is
that temporary object as a prvalue. _[<-- also under the section of functional notation explicit conversions so, yes.]_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Praetorian is right, `unsigned char` is explicitly a `simple-type-specifier` (7.1.6.2), which is a valid functional casting notation (5.2.3.1), so this starts to look more and more like a compiler bug

Comment: @Thibaut: From the grammar, `unsigned char` looks more like multiple `simple-type-specifiers` "concatenated", which is at odds with Table 10.

Comment: Yeah, following on from my previous comment, I've changed my mind about what's going on here - GCC is right here. Table 10 is not at odds with anything if you read it properly ;)

Comment: The grammar rule for *type-name* is *type_name*: *class-name* | *enum-name* | *typedef-name* | *simple-template-id*. (C++11 7.1.6.2/1). `unsigned char` can't match any of those productions.

Comment: @Casey: Indeed - a single _simple-type-specifier_ cannot result in `unsigned char`.

Comment: It looks like we all agree that this syntax is explicitly forbidden by the grammar then. Although the wording is not as clear as it could be.

Comment: Well, at least VS is back to being wrong. Everything's right with the world once more.

Comment: @Thibaut Grammatically, it makes sense. We can't have function names with spaces in them, so it's consistent to forbid multi-word function-style casts.

Comment: I've stolen it for the answer :P

Comment: Thanks a lot LightnessRacesinOrbit and @Casey. You rock.