# Why gcc doesn't recognize initialization like "unsigned int()" for C++11?

Tags: c++11, gcc, visual-c++, initialization, unsigned

```
int main()
{
    auto k = int();//ok
    auto i = unsigned int();//gcc error
    return 0;
}
```

The line of "auto i" leads to gcc reporint an eror:

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'unsigned'
```

While VC doesn't have problem on my code. Why is this, is this a bug of gcc or, should it use some extra parences?

Thanks.

Comment: You could just use `unsigned` instead of `unsigned int`. But why this differs for VS and gcc is a good question.

Comment: Clang doesn't like it either.

Comment: You could make it work with `using myint = unsigned int;` then `auto i = myint();`. But still I am curious to know why gcc and clang report errors for this.

Comment: Does this work with `unsigned short()`? is it just `unsigned` and `int` affected or any multi-word numeric like `auto d = long double()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202480/2352671