# Constructing `long double` rvalue

Tags: c++, syntax, casting, rvalue, long-double

Let's say I have the following C++ code:

```
#include <cmath>
long double fn_d() {
    return pow( double(4), double(3) );
}
long double fn_ld() {
    return powl( long double(4), long double(3) );
}
```

MSVC is happy with this, but both GCC and Clang get confused on the second function, writing (GCC's output):

```
<source>:6:34: error: expected primary-expression before 'long'
6 |     return powl( long double(4), long double(3) );
  |                                  ^~~~
```

Notice that `fn_d(...)` above, works just fine.  **Assuming this isn't a bug in both compilers, what am I supposed to do about it?**

---

Note: `(long double)(4)` (i.e., a cast) is not okay.  It trips `-Wold-style-cast` (which you should be using).  Maybe `static_cast<long double>(4)`?  This feels dirty: I'm constructing an object, not casting an `int`, even if the compiler will elide it.

Comment: either `4L` or `static_cast<long double>(4)`

Comment: `using long_double = long double;` and changing the `fn_ld` signature to use the typedef will fix the issue.

Comment: Note, that `double(4)` is an explicit type conversion, just as `static_cast<long double>(4)`, so they are equivalent semantically. So the "I'm constructing an object, not casting an int" is not 100% right.

Comment: @RichardCritten `4L` is long int, you're thinking of `4.L`

Comment: The solution in my case was just to use the `L` suffix. The actual problem turns out to be more-general, so I'm voting to close my own question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the original code is incorrect and it's a MSVC bug to silently accept it, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202296/constructor-style-casting-in-function-call-parameters) for standard references.

---

Since `powl` is a non-overloaded function of signature:

```
long double powl(long double x, long double y);
```

you can just write `powl(4, 3)`, there is implicit coversion from integer to long double.

In the more general case your options include `(long double)4`, `static_cast<long double>(4)`, `4.L`, and `4.0L`.  The `L` suffix combined with the presence of `.` in the literal means a `long double` literal.

---

> This feels dirty: I'm constructing an object, not casting an int, even if the compiler will elide it.

Maybe you have a misunderstanding in this area. The code `double(4)` is a cast; its official name is *explicit type conversion (functional notation)*. Casts are prvalues, except for some cases that are not relevant here.

There is literally (ha ha) no difference whatsoever in semantics between the different syntaxes that result in prvalue of type `double` and value `4`.

This is also true for class types; `(std::string)x`, `std::string(x)`, and `static_cast<std::string>(x)` are all identical in semantics.

Comment: I forgot to ask for it in my question, but I'm glad you added the clarifications about what's going on behind the scenes with explicit type conversion (but even besides this, this is best answer).¶ For an object type, my syntax would semantically call a constructor; it had been my impression primitive types did this too.

Comment: @imallett primitive types don't have constructors. For class types all of the syntaxes call a constructor

Comment: The point is, my previous mental model could be reproduced by assuming that primitive types have implicit, compiler-generated constructors.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ grammar does not allow you to have a space in the type name when you do `type(value)`.

Instead you can use the appropriate suffix instead of trying to use `type(value)`.  For a `long double` you can use `l`/`L` like

```
return pow( 4.0L, 3.0L );
```