# Is it allowed to instantiate a class without specified variable name in C++

Tags: c++

I have these two classes:

```
class Foo
{
public:
      Foo() { std::cout << "in Foo constructor" << std::endl; }
};
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() {};
    Bar(Foo foo);
private:
    Foo m_foo;
};

Bar::Bar(Foo foo) :
    m_foo(foo)
{
    std::cout << "in Bar constructor with argument Foo" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Bar bar(Foo()); // is something wrong here ?
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and excuted it , nothing printed on screen, what did `Bar bar(Foo())` do ? 
I have seen similarity in [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)   and   [Foo f = Foo(); // no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo(Foo)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776313/foo-f-foo-no-matching-function-for-call-to-foofoofoo-huh), but I still can't figure out.

Comment: Most vexing parse indeed. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the same without changing the semantics (ie. [not using the copy or assignment constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462773/c-copy-construct-construct-and-assign-question)), add parentheses to disambiguate the syntax (the compiler does not know if you declare a function locally or if you build an object, by default the former is prioritized by the C++ standard):

```cpp
int main() {
    Bar bar ( (Foo()) );
    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) that was posted in the comments, it is an issue with the C++ grammar itself, not much you can do about it.

Comment: `Bar bar = Foo();` will do the same thing (conversion by constructor).

Comment: Ah ok. What if `Foo` has a conversion operator to `Bar`?

Comment: If `Bar` defines a constructor that takes `Foo`, that takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

OK it has been pointed out that [compiler thinks that you are declaring a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec#). By **Pubby** and **Nbr44**. This is a way how to get around it. Just let the compiler know that you are declaring variable.

```
int main() {
    Bar bar = Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just `Bar bar = Foo();` is sufficient.

Comment: Warning, the semantics is not the same, you'll end up calling the assignment operator here. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462773/c-copy-construct-construct-and-assign-question) for example.

Comment: right, did not realize that. Edited...

Comment: @Mic: The answer in the post you indicated specifically says it is not assignment.

Comment: @Kupto: No, it wasn't, it involved a copy constructor in addition to the `Foo` constructor. Your fix only involves the `Foo` constructor. You never had assignment.

Comment: now I am lost... what did you mean by `The answer in the post you indicated specifically says it is not assignment.`?

Comment: @Kupto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2462819/315052

Comment: Admittedly I'm treading in self-proclaimed naivety, but won't this potentially introduce copy elision? I.e. construct a temp Bar initialized with Foo(), then fire the copy constructor for Bar to pull over the data, then the destructor of the temp? I realize most compilers optimize this, but they also tend to require the copy-ctor be available at compile-time even when its not used after optimization (or so I recall, anyway, perhaps wrongly).

Comment: @WhozCraig: You are correct, in the `Bar bar = Bar(Foo());` formulation, the copy constructor can be optimized away.

Comment: Absolutely, my bad. The copy constructor would be called and not the assignment operator (which would be called, but only in a statement separate from the construction).