# c++ valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) don't know what to initialize

Tags: c++, initialization, hashtable, valgrind

I've been trying to understand what havn't I initialized in this code and I completely(?) understand what is uninitialized but I don't know how to initialize it.

I am getting the error:

```
==11931== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==11931==    at 0x804ABA6: Hashtable<int>::put(int, int) (hash_table.h:169)
==11931==    by 0x8048F80: test_put() (hash_table_test.cpp:27)
==11931==    by 0x804A551: main (hash_table_test.cpp:52)
==11931==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==11931==    at 0x402ADFC: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==11931==    by 0x804A9AE: Hashtable<int>::Hashtable() (hash_table.h:64)
==11931==    by 0x8048F62: test_put() (hash_table_test.cpp:26)
==11931==    by 0x804A551: main (hash_table_test.cpp:52)
```

from the valgrind so apparantly I havn't been initializing correctly the c'tor for Hashtable class:

```
    Hashtable() :
            ht_keys(2), ht_size(0), dynamicArray(NULL) {
        dynamicArray = new Node[ht_keys];
        for (int i = 0; i < ht_keys; i++) {
            dynamicArray[i].delete_val = false;
            dynamicArray[i].key=0;
            dynamicArray[i].default_node = false;
        }
    }
```

the dynamic array is of type Node* which it's private fields are:

```
    bool delete_val;
    T element;
    int key;
    bool default_node;
```

the class Node is inside the class Hashtable.
how can I initialize dynamicArray?

here's the full code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "library2.h"
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

#ifndef HASH_TABLE_HPP_
#define HASH_TABLE_HPP_
#define DIV 2
//type T must have c'tor, operator !=

template<class T>
class Hashtable {
public:
    class Node {
    public:
        Node(const T t) :
                delete_val(false), element(t), key(0), default_node(true) {

        }
        Node(bool v, const Node& n) :
                delete_val(v), element(n.element), key(0), default_node(
                        n.default_node) {
        }
        Node(const Node& n) :
                delete_val(false), element(n.element), key(n.key), default_node(
                        n.default_node) {
        }
        Node() :
                delete_val(false), key(0), default_node(true) {
        }

        bool operator==(const Node* n) {
            if (n) {
                if (element != n->element || default_node != n->default_node) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        bool operator!=(const Node n) {
            if (!(*this == n)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        bool delete_val;
        T element;
        int key;
        bool default_node;
    };

    Hashtable() :
            ht_keys(2), ht_size(0), dynamicArray(NULL) {
        dynamicArray = new Node[ht_keys];
        for (int i = 0; i < ht_keys; i++) {
            dynamicArray[i].delete_val = false;
            dynamicArray[i].key=0;
            dynamicArray[i].default_node = false;
        }
    }

    //seriously damaged programming...
    Hashtable(Node* array, int HT_keys, int HT_size) :
            ht_keys(HT_keys), ht_size(HT_size) {
        dynamicArray = new Node[ht_keys];
        if (array != NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ht_keys; i++) {
                dynamicArray[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
    }
    Hashtable(const Hashtable& ht) {
        if (&ht == this) {
            return;
        }
        ht_keys = ht.ht_keys;
        ht_size = ht.ht_size;
        dynamicArray = new Node[ht_keys];
        for (int i = 0; i < ht.ht_keys; i++) {
            this->dynamicArray[i] = ht.dynamicArray[i];
        }
    }
    ~Hashtable() {
        delete[] this->dynamicArray;
    }
    Hashtable operator=(const Hashtable& ht) {
        Hashtable<T> newHT = ht;
        return newHT;
    }

    //Returns true if some value equal to value exists within the hash table.
    bool contains(Node n, int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > ht_keys || !n) {
            return false;
        }
        if (i == ht_keys) {
            return false;
        }
        //make sure that n.delete_val is not set as true.
        if (dynamicArray[i]->element == n.element
                && !dynamicArray[i]->delete_val) {
            return true;
        }
        if (dynamicArray[i]->delete_val) {
            return contains(n, i + 1);
        }
        return false;
        return true;
    }
    //Returns true if some key equal to key exists within the hash table.
    bool containsKey(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > ht_keys) {
            return false;
        }
        if (dynamicArray[i]->element && !dynamicArray[i]->delete_val) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //Returns true if some value equal to value exists within the hash table.
    bool containsValue(T e) {

        return true;
    }
    //Returns an enumeration of the values contained in the hash table.
    int enumeration() {
        return ht_size;
    }
    //Returns the object that contains the value associated with key.
    //If key is not in the hash table, a null object is returned.
    Node get(int i) {
        if (i >= 0) {
            return dynamicArray[i % ht_keys];
        }
        Node n;
        return n;
    }
    //Returns true if the hash table is empty;
    //returns false if it contains at least one key.
    bool isEmpty() {
        if (ht_size) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    //Returns an enumeration of the keys contained in the hash table.
    int keys();
    //Inserts a key and a value into the hash table.
    //Returns false if key isn't already in the hash table;
    //returns true if key is already in the hash table.
    bool put(T e, int i) {
        if (e && i > 0) {
            Node n;
            n.default_node = false;
            n.delete_val = false;
            n.key = i;
            n.element = e;
            //line 168
            for (int j = (i % ht_keys); j < ht_keys; j = ((j + 1) % ht_keys)) { //line 169
                if (!dynamicArray[j % ht_keys].element
                        || dynamicArray[j % ht_keys].delete_val) {
                    dynamicArray[j % ht_keys] = n;
                    ht_size++;
                    return true;
                }else if (i == (j + 1) % ht_keys) {
                    rehash();
                    return put(e, i);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool put_aux(Node n, int i, Node* Array, int HT_keys) {

        for (int j = (i % HT_keys); j < HT_keys; j = ((j + 1) % HT_keys)) {
            if (!Array[j % HT_keys].element || Array[j % HT_keys].delete_val) {
                Array[j % HT_keys] = n;
                return true;
            } else if (Array[j % HT_keys].element == n.element) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

//Increases the size of the hash table and rehashes all of its keys.
    void rehash() {
        int old_ht_keys = ht_keys;
        ht_keys = DIV * ht_keys;
        Node* newArray = new Node[ht_keys];
        if (ht_keys > DIV) {
            for (int j = 0; j < old_ht_keys; j++) {
                put_aux(dynamicArray[j],dynamicArray[j].key,newArray,ht_keys);
            }
        }
        delete[] dynamicArray;
        dynamicArray = newArray;
    }
//Removes key and its value.
//Returns the value associated with key.
//If key is not in the hash table, a null objecht_sizet is returned.
    T remove(int i) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < ht_keys) {
            Node deleted_node(true, dynamicArray[i % ht_keys]);
            dynamicArray[i % ht_keys] = deleted_node;
            ht_size--;
            return deleted_node.element;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
//Returns the number of entries in the hash table.
    int size() {
        return this->ht_size;
    }

private:
    int ht_keys;
    int ht_size;
    Node* dynamicArray;
};

#endif /* HASH_TABLE_HPP_ */
```

Comment: The full code you listed is hash_table.h correct? Is it the exact same hash_table.h as your valgrind output? Reason I ask is that the lines valgrind mentions appear to be a blank line and a rehash() call.

Comment: yes, although I am using a cpp file to call the functions from there (a testing file). that is why you can only see half of the functions mentioned in the valgrind

Comment: Understand the testing, but the posted code doesn't seem to match the valgrind output for hast_table.h. What line do you get for 169?

Comment: I see the problem, line 169 is the for loop in the function put. I will edit that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be complaining about the line `!dynamicArray[j % ht_keys].element` (on line 163 of the code you posted; this would be a lot easier if the code you posted matched the code valgrind was using; right now the code you posted is several lines shorter than the code valgrind is using).

You never initialize the `element` member when you allocate the memory in the constructor. You then attempt to use it here in a conditional statement. valgrind correctly warns you of the problem.

Comment: thanks for your comment, sorry for your waste of time matching the code to valgrind, though I recently edited the post with the correct lines in the code itself as a comment.

anywho, how would you suggest I initialize a template of type T?
I don't know how it is built, and that's why I let the default initializer of the new[] operator to initialize it by default, therefore the error.
if there's a better way to do so, please do tell...

Comment: Alright I've used the magnificent tool that is google and found the answer here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143022/how-to-correctly-initialize-variable-of-template-type)
it worked! thanks alot! :D