# How to value-initialize an object of a template type in C++03

Tags: c++, c++03, c++98, most-vexing-parse

Suppose I have a function template and want to declare a value-initialized object:

```
template<typename T>
void foo() {
    // declare and default-initialize 'x' of type 'T'
}
```

Can I do it?

- `T x;` fails for primitive types because it leaves them uninitialized,
- `T x();` fails because of the most vexing parse
- `T x = T();` requires a copy constructor and doesn't require the compiler elide the copy
- `T x{};` fails because we're not using C++11.

I'm hoping I'm being an idiot and overlooking something obvious, but I'm not seeing the answer.

Comment: `T x` is default initialization. Value initialization didn't even exist until C++03.

Comment: You're right, I've edited it in

Comment: In case you already use boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm

Comment: The Boost answer is probably the best generic answer; thanks! If you post an actual answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Pre c++11

```
T x = T();
```

read here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143022/how-to-correctly-initialize-variable-of-template-type)

```
T3 var3 = {};
```

> The third form, T3 var3 = {} initializes an aggregate, typically a "C-style" struct or a "C-style" array. However, the syntax is not allowed for a class that has an explicitly declared constructor.

[source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm)

Comment: The OP knows that but `T` needs to by copyable for this to work.

Comment: That's the best answer that I know of, but it's not perfect. I'm asking if there's a better one. That said, the fact that there weren't better answers at your link indicates there probably isn't a better one, so I do thank you for it. (I did some searching but didn't find that.)

Comment: Not sure if the one I just found is of any help, I edited my post.