# Initializing template variable for a linked list

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initialization

I'm creating a linked list class, which uses an internal `Link` class and a template class to define the types that can be stored in the linked list.

However, in my method `popValue` which should return template type `T`, I cannot initialise a default type (in this case, called `Point`), despite the fact that the type stored in each Link has a default constructor - which according to [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143022/how-to-correctly-initialize-variable-of-template-type), indicates that `T retval = T() / T{}` should work.

Additionally I dont see how the error message corresponds, given that `T retval` is not a reference type?

Hence, the method in question:

```
template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::popValue() {
    T retval = T(); //This doesnt work
    Point test = Point(); //But this is allowed?
    if (head != 0) {
        Link *n = head;
        retval = head->value;
        head = head->next;
        delete n;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Gives the following error `value-initialization of reference type 'Point&'`:

[image]

How can I initialise this template variable to a default value, so that if there is no elements in the LinkedList, this default value can be returned, given that the methods outlined in other questions don't seem to work?

Thanks very much,

David

**EDIT**

From comments, I looked at specialisation of the `LinkedList.h` and found I made the major error of using it as `LinkedList<Point&> list;`.
When used in template form, this means that `T` is trying to instantiate a reference type - which is not allowed.

For reference, I have included a concise code listing of what I thought would be the relevant code (but have removed non-significant includes, guard and namespaces for brevity)...:

**LinkedList.h**

```
template<typename T>
    class LinkedList {
    public:
        struct Link { ///< Struct inside the class LinkedList
            Link(T val): value(val), next(0){};
            T value;
            Link *next;
            ~Link() {
                delete next;
            } //Iteratively delete
        };
        T popValue(); ///< returns first element and deletes Link.
    private:
        Link *head; // this is the private member variable. It is just a pointer to the first Node
    };

#include "LinkedList.cpp" //Allows definition of template methods in .cpp file
```

**LinkedList.cpp (erroneous method only)**

```
    template<typename T>
    T LinkedList<T>::popValue() {
        T retval = T(); //This doesnt work
        Point test = Point(); // But this does
        if (head != 0) {
            Link *n = head;
            retval = head->value;
            head = head->next;
            delete n;
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: But then could I still use it for a type that isnt a `Point` object?

Comment: Could you provide a very short answer to show how this would be used for the LinkedList.h/.cpp (just a simple class description & constructor or single method would be fine)?

Comment: The compiler things `LinkedList` is being initialized with `T = Point&`. That's obviously not what you want. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @davidhood2 Your `popValue` function would be very confusing since it returns a perfectly valid value if the list is already empty.  Rather you throw an exception on an empty list than return something that could be mistaken  for a valid value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Normally throwing an exception would be my chosen option - but this is to be ported to an Arduino that doesn't support exceptions

Comment: @davidhood2 It seems I've misread the question. I've removed my other comments as they are misleading.

Comment: Can we see where you specialize the `LinkedList`? I have a feeling that it will look something like `LinkedList<Point&>` when you want `LinkedList<Point>`. Also don't do this: `#include "LinkedList.cpp"`. Either implement it all in the header or change the name of LinkedList.cpp to something like LinkedList.impl or anything but cpp. Far less surprise, anguish and confusion when someone tries to compile the cpp file.

Comment: @user4581301 You are right; I never checked my original specialisation of `LinkedList` which I found was `LinkedList<Point&>`. I've updated the question to take this into account...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message

> [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of reference type 'Point&'

The T is highly possible a reference type.

You can check this by:

```
static_assert(std::is_reference<T>::value == false, "");
```

By using [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) ([`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) is also useful in this case), you can get the type referred to by T, which will enable you to define a non reference variable.

```
#include <type_traits>
int main() {
  using T = int &;
  std::remove_reference_t<T> b = std::remove_reference_t<T>();
  return 0;
}
```

In case "x_t" isn't declared:

```
#include <type_traits>
int main() {
  using T = int &;
  typename std::remove_reference<T>::type b =
      typename std::remove_reference<T>::type();
  return 0;
}
```

---

Less related:

"Storing" reference will cause you lots of troubles, because normally we don't check whether a reference refers to nothing, `&ref != nullptr`. And likely, you will not want to implement popValue this way:

```
template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::popValue() {
    if (head != 0) {
        Link *n = head;
        T retval = head->value;
        head = head->next;
        delete n;
        return retval;
    } else {
      std::remove_reference_t<T> x = std::remove_reference_t<T>();
      return x; // very bad when T is reference
    }
}
```

Returning the element popped by output parameter is still an option (Just keep the output parameter unchanged when the list is empty), but maybe you just want to store no reference.